# What do you call variables like "%(ec2_region)" in my cloud-init?

Tags: cloud-init

What do you call these variables in my `cloud-init` file,

```yaml
- http://%(ec2_region)s.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/
- http://%(availability_zone)s.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/
- http://%(region)s.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/
```

You can see here variables like `%(region)` are these available to all things in `cloud-init`? Where are these documented?

Answer (score 1):

This is called instance metadata. Cloud providers expose metadata to cloud instances which cloud-init then stores and can be used in a few different contexts, such as jinja-templated cloud-init userdata.

Cloud-init instance metadata is documented here: https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/instancedata.html